# When is a laurent series meromorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

> When is a Laurent series meromorphic?

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $D_r(a)\setminus\{a\}$ and $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n\in Z}c_n (z-a)^n$ be its unique Laurent series on $D_r(a)\setminus\{a\}$ Then, I want to show that $f$ is meromorphic if and only if $\exists N_0 \in Z$ such that $c_n = 0\; \forall n < N_0$

I am struggling in arriving at this result.

Definition of meromorphic that I am using:

> Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\Omega \setminus \{z_1, \ldots z_n\}$. Then
> $f$ is meromorphic on $\Omega$, if for each $z_i$, $\exists D_p(z_i)$
> inside $\Omega$ such that $g, h$ are holomorphic on $D_p(z_i)$ and $h$
> is never zero and $\frac{g}{h} = f$ on $ D_p(z_i)\setminus\{z_i\}$

Comment: What definition of meromorphic are you using here? The most common one is "a function which is holomorphic except on a set of isolated points, each of which are poles." The condition on Laurent series you've written is precisely the definition of a having a pole of order $N_0$ at $z=a$ though, and since $a$ is the only potential isolated singularity of the Laurent series in that disk, there's nothing to do (unless you're working with some other definitions than the ones I've stated).

Comment: @Glare I added the definition that I am using in the end

Comment: I think your definition should read "$g$ is never zero in $D$" as opposed to "$h$ is never zero $D$"

Comment: @Glare I am not sure about that, but I will check it again with my instructor.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, they probably meant "$h$ is not identically $0$." That would be a valid definition. The point is we need to allow for things like $h(z) = (z-a)^n$, since $f(z) = 1/(z-a)^n$ is certainly meromorphic.

Comment: yes, $h$ is not identically $0$. Any idea how to prove the equivalence of these two definitions or where I might find it? there must be authors who are using this definition right

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is meromorphic in $D_r(a)$. Then there are holomorphic functions $g,h$ defined on $D_r(a)$ with $h$ not identically $0$ and $f=g/h$ in $D_r(a)\setminus\{a\}$. Since $f$ is well-defined and finite at each point in $D_r(a)$ other than $a$ we may assume $h$ is only $0$ at $z=a$. This zero must also be of finite order (otherwise $h$ would be identically $0$, say, by Taylor expansion), so we may write $h(z) = (z-a)^mk(z)$ for some holomorphic $k(z)$ satisfying $k(z)\neq 0$ in some neighborhood $D_{r'}(a)$ of $a$. In this neighborhood, we have
$$(z-a)^mf(z) = \frac{g(z)}{k(z)},$$
and the right-hand side is analytic since $k\neq 0$ here, meaning we get a power series expansion
$$(z-a)^mf(z) = \sum_{k\geq 0} d_k(z-a)^k.$$
Dividing both sides by $(z-a)^m$ gives a Laurent series expansion valid in $D_{r'}(a)\setminus\{a\}\subset D_r(a)\setminus\{a\}$. Yet the Laurent series is unique; since the coefficients of $(z-a)^n$ for $n<-m$ are zero in our new one, we must have $c_n = 0$ for $n<-m$ in our original Laurent series.

The converse is easier. If $c_n = 0$ for $n<N_0$, then in $D_r(a)\setminus\{a\}$ we have
$$(z-a)^{N_0}f(z) = c_{N_0}+c_{N_0+1}(z-a)+c_{N_0+2}(z-a)^2+\dotsm.$$
Letting $g(z)$ be the power series on the right-hand side, we see $g$ and $h(z):=(z-a)^{N_0}$ are analytic on the disk, $h(z)$ is not identically $0$, and $f=g/h$ on the punctured disk. Thus $f$ is meromorphic, as desired.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll edit it to use uniqueness of Laurent series instead.

Comment: To prove the uniqueness: if $b_n\ne 0$ and $\sum_k b_k z^k$ converges for $r<|z|<R$ then $\int_{|z|=(r+R)/2}z^{-1-n} \sum_k b_k z^k dz=2i\pi b_n$ so  $\sum_k b_k z^k$ can't be the zero function

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The OP mentioned the Laurent series for $f$ was unique in the problem statement though, so I'm going to say I don't need to prove it.